Tests for signing polkadot transaction
I am looking for any official tests in javascript that are used for transaction signing.
Basically a test that has transaction parameters, a private key, raw transaction (build from transaction parameters) that gets signed with the private key and the expected signature.
I think this is quite a basic test, but can't find any examples. I looked at https://github.com/polkadot-js/ and other libraries but can't seem to find any examples.

You can refer papi aka polkadot api. Link docs: https://papi.how/typed/tx#sign

are you looking for polkadot-js examples? You can check the docs here https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/make-transfer
if you are looking for specific tests in the polkadot js API codebase, you can check the spec file of the function https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Apolkadot-js/api%20path%3Aspec&type=code

I am not looking for examples. I am looking for a concrete test, I want to create my own signer but can't find any official test so I know to cover all edge cases etc.
